# Syntax Error Message for mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm encountering this error when trying to load a .sql file to PHPMyAdmin:

[image: Error Message]

Here is what the .sql code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
    `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `product_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `product_image` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: Your actual error is that the `category` table isn't properly defined. Missing some columns and the closing bracket.

Comment: Notice how it complained "hear" `CREATE` of `product`.  Then either the `CREATE` is "wrong", or the thing immediately before it (a comma) is "wrong".

Answer (score 1):

When creating the `category` table, you are not closing the parentheses that you opened. Your statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'category' (
    'category_id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'category_name' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

needs to be closed with a `);`

You also need to remove the trailing comma `,`.

Comment: @arieljannai   I understand these are likely basic concerns... But this is how I learn...  My questions are actually code related questions...

Comment: And I don't understand #1046 - No database selected... The database does exist, and so do the tables...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing brackets of your queries (perhaps some more columns, you'll see it after you fix the brackets)

Comment: And I fixed the brackets and I get... CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (  
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

Comment: And I'm using pictures because it's more visual... and I am trying to work with a .sql file...

Comment: tables 'category' and 'product' are actually created in the DB... How do I add to it...